# Recurring scheduled task help

Tags: cron, wp-cron

I'm trying to set up a scheduled task in my Wordpress installation which will (eventually) run a script to send an email once a day with a load of data in.

However I can't seem to get a scheduled task to fire at all. I am testing it with a 2 minute interval to see if I can get it working. What I have so far is below, and is at the bottom of my `functions.php` file. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_definer');
function my_cron_definer($schedules){
    $schedules['twomin'] = array(
        'interval'=> 120,
        'display'=>  __('Once Every 2 Minutes')
    );
    return $schedules;
}

add_action('my_periodic_action','my_periodic_function');
function my_periodic_function(){
    mail('email@address.co.uk','Test!', 'Test Message');
}
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'twomin', 'my_periodic_action');
```

I'm aware my Wordpress site needs to be getting it's pages visited for the function to run, so I have been clicking around on the site hoping to trigger my function but no luck!

**Note:** I have swapped my real email address out!

Answer (score 2):

You have to schedule your event in a hook, for example in `after_setup_theme` or `wp` actions:

```
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_definer');
function my_cron_definer($schedules){
    $schedules['twomin'] = array(
        'interval'=> 120,
        'display'=>  __('Once Every 2 Minutes')
    );
    return $schedules;
}

add_action('my_periodic_action','my_periodic_function');
function my_periodic_function(){
    mail('email@address.co.uk','Test!', 'Test Message');
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse8170_setup_events' );
// or add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse8170_setup_events' );
function wpse8170_setup_events() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_periodic_action' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'twomin', 'my_periodic_action');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have given your example a go but I'm still having no luck. Is there anything else you're aware of (not necessarily related to the above code) that could be preventing it from working?

Comment: @Probocop it's very strange... try to display something in your `my_periodic_function` call to check if it works. If it works, then `mail` function is not working.

Comment: I've got a test script written (which will eventually be the scheduled script) that has the wp_mail (and has had mail) function within which works if I manually run the script. Unless there is a reason why the mail functions wouldn't work from within functions.php?

Comment: While I'd still like to know how to do this, I've abandoned this approach in favour of using a scheduled task instead (site is in IIS). Thanks!